# Coloring of collapsed threads in mutt

Tags: colors, mutt

I'm trying to figure out the syntax of colouring collapsed threads in the mutt index. [The documentation for mutt patterns](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/manual-4.html#ss4.2) doesn't seem to include a description of how this works, and so far I've been completely unable to figure it out by trial and error.

What I'd like is for collapsed threads that contain any unread (new) messages to be *always* coloured green. If collapsed threads *with no unread messages* contain any flagged messages, then I'd like them to be red.

So far, every set of patterns I've tried results in threads that contain both flagged and unread messages being coloured red (I want them green).

These work:

```
color index green default "~N"          # unread messages
color index green default "~N~F"        # unread flagged messages
color index red   default "~F"          # flagged messages
color index green default "~v~(~N)"     # collapsed thread with unread
```

But these don't:

```
color index green default "~v~(~N~F)"       # attempt to keep threads with unread green
color index red   default "~v~(~F)"         # colours collapsed threads with flagged and unread red
color index red   default "~v~(!~N~F)"      # ditto
color index red   default "~v~(^!~N~F)"     # ditto
color index red   default "~v~(~F)~(!~N)"   # ditto
color index red   default "~v~(~F)~v~(!~N)" # ditto
```

I've also tried switching the order of the "~v~(~F)" and "~v~(~N)" commands in the file, but the "flagged" rule always seems to take precedence over the "new" rule.

Ideally I'd like to understand how the syntax for colouring collapsed threads works, but at this point I'd happily settle for a set of rules that achieves the colourscheme described above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following successfully:

```
color index yellow  default "~v~(!~N)~(!~F)" # collapsed thread with no New or Flagged
color index red     default "~v~(~F)~(!~N)"  # collapsed thread with Flagged but no New
color index green   default "~v~(~N)"        # collapsed thread with New
```

Unfortunately you've tried these... Version mismatch? I'm using mutt 1.5.23.

Comment: I having trouble understand how this answers the author's question.  The question about which version the author is using seems more like a comment that should have been asked before publishing this answer.

Comment: Not sure why it didn't work for me before when I tried it, but your solution works for me now. Thanks!

Comment: @Ramhound - I concur. however, I didn't have the rep to comment.